# OpenBSD logins via SSH seem to be ignoring my configured radius server

Tags: ssh, ldap, radius, openbsd

I've installed and configured a radius server upon my
localhost - it is delegating auth to a remote LDAP server.

Initially things look good:  I can test via the console:

```
# export user=skemp
# export pass=xxx
# radtest $user $pass localhost 1812 $secret
Sending Access-Request of id 185 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
    User-Name = "skemp"
    User-Password = "xxx"
    NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.1.168
    NAS-Port = 1812
rad_recv: Access-Accept packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=185,
```

Similarly I can use the login tool to do the same thing:

```
bash-4.0# /usr/libexec/auth/login_radius -d -s login $user radius
Password: $pass
authorize
```

However remote logins via SSH are failing, and so are invokations
of "login" started by root.  Looking at /var/log/radiusd.log I
see no actual log of success/failure which I do see when using either
of the previous tools.

Instead sshd is just logging:

```
 sshd[23938]: Failed publickey for skemp from 192.168.1.9
 sshd[23938]: Failed keyboard-interactive for skemp from 192.168.1.9 port 36259 ssh2
 sshd[23938]: Failed password for skemp from 192.168.1.9 port 36259 ssh2
```

In /etc/login.conf I have this:

```
# Default allowed authentication styles
auth-defaults:auth=radius:

...

radius:\
    :auth=radius:\
    :radius-server=localhost:\
    :radius-port=1812:\
    :radius-timeout=1:\
    :radius-retries=5:
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issues with configuring OpenBSD to deligate authentications to a ldap server. The only way I could get it to work was by adding a user to the local db, e.g.

useradd -s /bin/ksh -L ldap new_user

In your case, it would be something like

useradd -s /bin/ksh -L radius new_user2

However, since you have to manually create a user entry for each machine that is using ldap for authentication, it would undermine the need for a centralized ldap authentication server. I am also out of ideas.

Comment: I may be misreading, but I think that what you complain is actually expected functionality. The idea is that you have user accounts on a local system, and you would like them to be authenticated via a remote system (radius, ldap, etc.). If there is no local account on the local system in the first place, then there is nothing to authenticate against on the remote system. So you necessarily have to create the accounts you want on the local system.